# Moving objects in an array using UITouch SpriteKit

Tags: nsmutablearray, scrollbar, sprite, sprite-kit

I'm trying to move SKSpritenode in an array like a scrollbar where all objects move together according to the move location:

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

    NSEnumerator *e = [_blockStream objectEnumerator];
    PBAIceBlock *block;
    while (block = [e nextObject]) 
    {
        //this says the expresion is not assignable
        block.position.y += location.y;
    }   
}
```

Where the comments says, I get an error, could some one please point me in the right direction on how to implement something like this?
Using Sprite kit in xcode 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to create a CGPoint to store a value. set that value in touchesBegan, then:

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

    int yOFFSET = location.y - _touchLocation.y ;
    NSLog(@"yOFFSET : %d", yOFFSET);
    NSEnumerator *e = [_blockStream objectEnumerator];
    PBAIceBlock *block;
    while (block = [e nextObject]) {
        CGPoint _center = block.position;
        _center.y += yOFFSET;
        block.position = _center;
    }
    _touchLocation = location;


}
```

This problem happened because you cannot call the position.y specifically.